# PHP Error only present in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer

Okay this has baffled me. My script works in Mozilla but not IE. I get this error in IE:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/properties/yh96gapdna8amyhhmgcniskcvk9p0u37/) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /homepages/19/d375499187/htdocs/sitename/include/session.php on line 602

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpJkiaF3' to 'uploads/properties/yh96gapdna8amyhhmgcniskcvk9p0u37/' in /homepages/19/d375499187/htdocs/sitename/include/session.php on line 602
```

my code at Session.php is:

```
function addPhoto($subphotoSize,$subphotoType,$subphotoTmpname,$subphotoDesc,$subfieldID,$subsessionid){
    global $database, $form;

    /* Get random string for directory name */
    $randNum = $this->generateRandStr(10);

    $maxFileSize = 2500000; // bytes (2 MB)
    $filerootpath = PHOTOS_DIR.$subsessionid."/";
    if($subphotoType == "image/png"){
        $filename = $randNum.".png";
    } else if ($subphotoType == "image/jpeg"){
        $filename = $randNum.".jpg";
    }
    $fullURL = $filerootpath.$filename;

    /* Image error checking */
    $field = "photo";
    if(!$subphotoTmpname){
        $form->setError($field, "* No file selected");
    } else {
        if($subphotoSize > $maxFileSize) {
            $form->setError($field, "* Your photo is above the maximum of ".$maxFileSize."Kb");
        } else if (!is_dir($filerootpath)){
            mkdir($filerootpath,0777);
            chmod($filerootpath,0777);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($subphotoTmpname, "$fullURL");
    }
    /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
    if($form->num_errors > 0){
        return 1;  //Errors with form
    } else {
        if($subfieldID == "1"){ // If the first field...
            $is_main_photo = 1;
        } else {
            $is_main_photo = 0;
        }
        if(!$database->addNewPhoto($ownerID,$subphotoDesc,$fullURL,$userSession,$is_main_photo, $subsessionid)){
            return 2; // Failed to add to database
        }
    }
    return 0; // Success
}
```

It creates the folder no problem but doesnt do anything else.

Comment: Can you print `$fullURL` and show me the output?

Comment: What are you passing into this function? See if they differ between the two browsers. If you're passing in filenames from `$_FILES`, for example, try something like `var_dump($_FILES);` for both IE and Firefox and see if they differ.

Comment: var_dump displays: array(1) { ["photo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "6122.jpg" ["type"]=> string(11) "image/pjpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpu8oMmx" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(493526)

Comment: Thanks, I've sussed it out the error, it is the mime type being a progressive jpeg. I now have a header error that i dont get in Mozilla either. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/19/d375499187/htdocs/sitename/process.php:265) in /homepages/19/d375499187/htdocs/sitename/process.php on line 271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a log message to see what's the value of $subphotoType. My guess is that when you upload the file from Internet Explorer it's neither image/png nor image/jpeg, in which case $filename will be empty because you don't have an else clause.

```
if($subphotoType == "image/png"){
    $filename = $randNum.".png";
} else if ($subphotoType == "image/jpeg"){
    $filename = $randNum.".jpg";
} else {
    // No else! $filename will be empty.
}
```

If you tune your error reporting settings properly you should see a notice saying you are trying to use an undefined variable.

Comment: Im afriad that didnt work. I have javascript in the form to prevent other file types. Thanks anyway

Comment: On the client side you are probably checking the file extension, and on the server you are checking the file content-type, which is a different thing. Check and see - add an else clause with die("Got handled Content-Type: $subphotoType");

Comment: You were actually right, but the else condition didnt work because i was uploading regardless of those if statements. Thanks